# Transaction in Stored procedure

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, transactions

Please can someone help.

I have several stored procedures in a job, and In one of them I Begin a transaction to delete some rows and if rows are greater than 10 then I Roll back. however if there are not I don't want to commit straight away, because 2 stored procedure later I do something similar. however if count is greater than 10 in this instance I want it rolled back all the way to when I stared the transaction (two stored procedures ago)

Is it possible to start a transaction in a store procedure and have multiple roll backs and Commit right at the end somewhere or do I have to put all the code into 1 store procedure to do that?

Comment: In my opinion it is best to avoid commits and rollbacks within stored procedures altogether.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use @@TRANCOUNT to determine whether or not you have any outstanding uncommitted transactions and then use that to dictate the logic of your stored procedures.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Proc1
AS
BEGIN
    BEGIN TRANSACTION
    // DO STUFF
    IF (@@ROWCOUNT > 10)
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
END

CREATE PROCEDURE Proc2
AS
BEGIN
    IF (@@TRANCOUNT > 0)
    BEGIN
        // DO STUFF
        IF (@@ROWCOUNT > 10)
            ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
    END
END

CREATE PROCEDURE Proc3
AS
BEGIN
    IF (@@TRANCOUNT > 0)
    BEGIN
        // DO STUFF
        IF (@@ROWCOUNT > 10)
            ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
        ELSE
            COMMIT TRANSACTION
    END
END
```